# How to traverse a list of custom class obj containing a map and build another map with aggregation

Tags: scala, collections

I have a list of custom class object that contains can contain a `map(String -> Integer)`. I want to aggregate all quantities from the list grouped by the key. I don't need anything else from the list.
For example:

```
  case class Student(name: String, standard: String, scores: List[Option[Map[String, java.lang.Integer]]])

  val studentList = List(Student("John", "First", List(Option(Map("Sub1" -> 10)), Option(Map("Sub2" -> 20)), Option(Map("Sub3" -> 30)))),
    Student("Jane", "First", List(Option(Map("Sub1" -> 10)), Option(Map("Sub2" -> 20)), Option(Map("Sub3" -> 30)))),
    Student("Jimmy", "First", List(Option(Map("Sub1" -> 10)), Option(Map("Sub2" -> 20)), Option(Map("Sub3" -> 30)))))

  val totalScoresByName = studentList.groupMapReduce(_.name)(_.scores)(_ + _)
```

Using **+** in `groupMapReduce` method shows error

> value + is not a member of List[Option[Map[String, Integer]]]

How can I create a map of `name -> totalScore` out of this list which looks like this

```
John -> 60
Jane -> 60
Jimmy -> 60
```

Comment: `.groupMapReduce(_.name)(_.scores.flatten.flatMap(_.values).map(_.intValue).sum)(_ + _)`

Comment: Thanks @Dima, this works in 2.11.13, what is equivalent for this in version 2.11.11 of Scala which doesn't have groupMapReduce method.

Comment: @Dima This produces `Map(John -> 60, Jane -> 60, Jimmy -> 60)` instead of `John -> 60, Jane -> 90, Jimmy -> 120`

Comment: @DmytroMitin my bad, 60 is the correct output for all three, updated the numbers now.

Comment: @JaySaraf While there is `groupMapReduce` in 2.13 https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/collection/immutable/List.html , in 2.11-2.12 there are `groupBy`, `map`, `reduce` https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

Comment: @DmytroMitin That is correct, I found that out but I can't get it working in version 2.11.11.  I tried following but I'm missing something here `studentList.groupBy(_.name).map(x => (x._2.flatten(_.scores.flatten.flatMap(_.keys)), x._2.flatten(_.scores.flatten.flatMap(_.values).map(_.intValue())))).reduce((a,b) => a._2 + b._2)`

Comment: It's quite literal translation:
`.groupBy(_.name).mapValues(_.flatMap(_.scores.flatten.flatMap(_.values).map(_.intValue)).sum).toMap`
You should really try to figure these things out yourself if you are going to learn anything. This is not hard: just look at the signatures of the functions you are using and types of inputs you are sending in, see where there is a mismatch, and figure out why. E.g. `.map(x => (x._2.flatten(_.scores.flatten.flatMap(_.keys))` - this doesn't make any sense at all: x._2 is a list of `Student`, `flatten` doesn't accept any parameters etc ...